# Сериализация графа объектов

Tags: java, xml, сериализация

Только только начал изучать сериализацию и сериализацию в xml.

Предположим у нас есть класс `Company`. У компании есть поля `parent`( тоже объект класса `Company`) и дочки(тоже объекты класса `Company`). У родителей и дочек точно также могут быть свои родители и дочки). И так мы созданем несколько компаний и помещаем их в `ArrayList`. Дальше вызваем сериализатор в xml файл. Получается что при сериализации каждого объекта из листа сериализуется весь граф объект, то есть сериализуем первый элемент, у него вызывается сериализация родителя и дочек, у родителя и дочек также вызвается сериализация своего родителя и дочек.

То есть получается, что при сериализации каждого элелемента сериализуется весь граф объектов. Вопрос так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы избежать бесконечно вложенной сериализации и циклических ссылок, нужно соответствующим образом настроить сериализатор. В таком случае он будет не вкладывать элементы, описывающие ваши объекты, друг в друга, а создаст ссылки по какому-то идентификатору.

Конкретная реализация зависит от того, какой сериализатор вы используете:

- в JAXB это делается через `@XmlIDREF`,
- в XStream - через `setMode(XPATH_RELATIVE_REFERENCES)`, `setMode(XPATH_ABSOLUTE_REFERENCES)` и `setMode(ID_REFERENCES)`.